# Shopify meta fields variant value

Tags: html, css, shopify, meta

Is it possible to display the value of a variant meta field in shopify? I have added it with the metafields editor app.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take a look at the following page to get an idea of how to ask a "good" question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... My main questions for you are what research have you done on the subject and what have you tried already?

Comment: i have tried googling and searching on SO... but none of the code seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

First you need to get the variant of the product. You can do this [several ways](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant).

Here we'll assume this piece of code is within a product page template and just loop through all the available variants of a product and display some metafield data. **Namespace** and **key** are the values you added to the variant.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{{variant.metafields.namespace.key}}
{% endfor %}
```

More information can be found [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield).

Comment: thanks. This works, but doesn´t change the displayed value after changing the variant?